# Terraform: pulling tag values from modules

Tags: module, terraform, lookup

I have a tags module that I would like to look up values from for resources in terraform 0.13.2

tags.tf

```
    module "tags" {
      source             = "git::ssh://git@blah.git?ref=v0.2.3"
      product            = var.product
      tag3               = var.tag3
      tag4               = var.tag4
      tag5               = var.tag5
      tag6               = var.tag6
      tag7               = "tag7"
      tag8               = "tag8"
      tag9               = "tag9"
      tag10              = "tag10"
      componentInfo      = "componentinfo"
    }
```

app.tf

```
  tags = {
      source        = lookup(module.tags.tags,"source")
      componentInfo = lookup(module.tags.tags,"componentInfo") 
  }
```

However, when I run this I get:

```
    10:39:06        Error: Invalid function argument
    10:39:06        
    10:39:06        
    10:39:06        Warning: Value for undeclared variable
    10:39:06        
    10:39:06        The root module does not declare a variable named "aws_env" but a value was
    10:39:06        found in file "vars/egdp-dev-us-east-1.tfvars". To use this value, add a
    10:39:06        "variable" block to the configuration.
    10:39:06        
    10:39:06        Using a variables file to set an undeclared variable is deprecated and will
    10:39:06        become an error in a future release. If you wish to provide certain "global"
    10:39:06        settings to all configurations in your organization, use TF_VAR_...
    10:39:06        environment variables to set these instead.
    10:39:06        
    10:39:06        
    10:39:06        Warning: Deprecated Resource
    10:39:06        
    10:39:06        The null_data_source was historically used to construct intermediate values to
    10:39:06        re-use elsewhere in configuration, the same can now be achieved using locals
    10:39:06        
    10:39:06          on avro-gen-layer.tf line 30, in resource "aws_s3_bucket_object" "avro-gen-bucket":
    10:39:06          30:       source        = lookup(module.tags.tags,"source")
    10:39:06            |----------------
    10:39:06            | module.tags.tags is object with 16 attributes
    10:39:06        
    10:39:06        Invalid value for "inputMap" parameter: the given object has no attribute
    10:39:06        "source".
```

I have seen this same code pattern elsewhere in github running terraform version 0.12.3. I have trimmed the example for brevity.

The following works; however, there are too many tags defined for the s3 bucket I'm trying to configure so I wanted to filter it down to only the most important tags:

```
  tags = merge(
    module.tags.tags,
    {
        "Name" = "datahub_producer_td"
    }
  )
```

Any help would be appreciated.

**Update**

I missed that the source was a terraform module that has it's own outputs. Source is not one of those output so the first lookup wouldn't have worked since it was not an output, but it seems componentInfo should have but got the same error.

here is the output.tf of that module.

output.tf

```
    data "null_data_source" "tags" {
      count = length(keys(local.all_tags))
    
      inputs = {
        key                 = element(keys(local.all_tags), count.index)
        value               = element(values(local.all_tags), count.index)
        propagate_at_launch = "true"
      }
    }
    
    output "tags" {
      value = local.all_tags
    }
    
    output "asg_tags" {
      value = data.null_data_source.asg_tags.*.outputs
    }
```

Comment: How your `tags` module is defined? Do you output any tags in it?

Comment: Just as shown above - no output defined.  I didn't think I needed this since it is not a child or root module.  

I just checked the sample and the lookup code is there - the same way version 13.2.  I must be missing something here...

Comment: I added the original issue I'm trying to correct; too many tags for an s3 bucket.

Comment: I don't understand how you have no output, and yet you can reference `module.tags.tags` and get an object with 16 attributes. You would have had to declare an output named `tags` inside the tags module for that to be possible. I feel like you aren't showing all the code. Also this statement: "it is not a child or root module" makes no sense to me, what else can a module be except a child of root, or a child of another module? It's also not clear how any of the code you included is actually solving the root problem of "bucket has too many tags". Are you sure this is all the code?

Comment: I see now that my module tags.tf only has 11 attributes defined.  Where is it getting 16?

Also, if output is required, why does the message say there is a tags object with 16 attributes. Also why does merge work fine?

I do need to get to the bottom of this discrepancy 11 vs 16.

Comment: I have updated to show more ot the true size of tags and also I included more of the error with the warnings in case that matters as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so "source" is **not** in the tags module - so there's that, and bingo it's exactly what the log says :facepalm:.  Also, the index for `"componentInfo"` is `"ComponentInfo"`...

It is much easier to see what is going on if I move these attributes to locals then use the commandline console `terraform console` to explore the variables, and sure enough module.tags.tags is an object with 17 attributes just like it says.

To make this a little more compact I looked for a way to do what python calls "dictionary comprehensions" and I found [this](https://blog.gruntwork.io/terraform-tips-tricks-loops-if-statements-and-gotchas-f739bbae55f9#1254)

I was not able to find out how to use the if clause for an attribute filter; however, I was able to filter a list, then filter the attributes:

```
tags = merge(
    module.tags.tags,
    {
        "Name" = local.artifact
    }
)
s3_keys = [for k in keys(local.tags):k if contains([
    "ComponentInfo"],k)]
s3_tags = {for k in local.s3_keys: k => local.tags[k]}
```

In this way it is possible to search through and select only the tags you need for a particular object since not all objects have the same tagging requirements.

Of course this work is probably better suited for the tags module.

Also, `lookup(module.tags.tags,"ComponentInfo")` does work

Answer (score 1):

You are treating the tags module as if it is a map, so should use `locals` instead, with a map object, like this:

```
locals {
  tags = {
    source  = "source"
    product = "product"
  }
}


# Example usages:

resource "a_resource" "my_resource" {
  lookup_tags = {
      source  = lookup(local.tags,"source")
      product = lookup(local.tags,"product") 
  }

  local_tags = local.tags

  merge_tags = merge(
    local.tags,
    {
        "Name" = "datahub_producer_td"
    }
  )
}
```

If you DO need to use a module then you should have an output that returns a map

```
output "tags" {
  value = {
    source  = "source"
    product = "product"
  }
}
```

Comment: Though I shortened my tags example,  the log shows there are 16 attributes (though I only defined 11),  and these attributes merge just fine as I have said. The question is - if these attributes are there then why are they not available for interpolation.

Comment: I will try this later tonight to see if it works

Comment: I see the problem the structure of the module appears to be just attributes; however, the source: "git::ssh://git@blah.git?ref=v0.2.3" defines outputs.  More later when I get this working...

Comment: I got it working by using a more recent version of git::ssh://git@blah.git with less outputs defined and using merge. However; I am still unable to filter the defined tags.  As the log shows, there is a module with 16 attributes (that was defined as output, I just didn't know that at the time); is there any way to use interpolation to pick one of those?